# Creating function to plot in R

Tags: r, function, plot

I have my code (model) in R:

```
library(ggplot2)
V <- function(c, E, HS, EC_50) E / (1 + exp(HS * (c - EC_50)))


HS <- 1
log_EC50 <- log(1e-3)
E <- 0

log_c <- seq(-12, 0, by = 0.1)
df <- data.frame(log_c = log_c, response = V(log_c, E, HS, log_EC50))


ggplot(df, aes( response)) +  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.03)
```

I want to create a function that will draw a histogram just like in my code but will take into account changes in parameters, e.g. HS, E.

Please help

Comment: Running your code produces a "histogram" that is simply a single rectangle at point 0, since V always returns 0 when E is 0. What variables are you trying to show on the x and y axes?

Comment: @AllanCameron Set `E <- 1` and the plot will show something.

Comment: @RuiBarradas sure, though I wonder if a plot of log_c versus response is more appropriate here. Difficult know without more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap `ggplot` into function, like:

```r
library(ggplot2)

log_c <- seq(-12, 0, by = 0.1)
E <- 1
HS <- 1
log_EC50 <- log(1e-3)

V <- function(c, E, HS, EC_50) {
  E / (1 + exp(HS * (c - EC_50)))
}

a <- function(log_c, E, HS, log_EC_50) {
  df <- data.frame(log_c = {{log_c}}, response = V({{log_c}}, {{E}}, {{HS}}, {{log_EC50}}))
  ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes( response)) +  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.03)
}

a(log_c, E=1, HS=2, log_EC50)
```

[image]

```r
a(log_c, E=1, HS=5, log_EC50)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: just to note, the `{{ }}` notation here is unnecessary. because you are only feeding in numbers you can just use the variables directly.